# Calculating the inverse of a formal power series

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, power-series

I am learning about power series (in the discrete mathematics context).

A formal power series over $\mathbb{C}$ is a sequence $(a_0,a_1,a_2,...)$ with $a_k \in \mathbb{C}$.
We define the addition of two power series as
$(a_0,a_1,a_2,...)+ (b_0,b_1,b_2,...)=(a_0+b_0,a_1+b_1,a_2+b_2,...)$

We define the multiplication with a constant $\lambda \in \mathbb{C}$ as
$\lambda (a_0,a_1,a_2,...)=(\lambda a_0,\lambda a_1, \lambda a_2,...)$

Further, we define the multiplication of two power series as follows:
$(a_0,a_1,a_2,...)(b_0,b_1,b_2,...)=(c_0,c_1,c_2, \dots)$ where
$c_n=\sum_{k=0}^n a_k b_{n-k}$ (1)

One can identify $(a_0,a_1,a_2,...)$ as $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}a_kx^k$

Now I want to do some examples.
Let $f(z)=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}(k+1)z^k$ be a formal power series.
I want to find the multiplicative inverse of it.

This means I want to solve $(1,2,3,4,...,(k+1),...)(b_0,b_1,b_2,...)=(1,0,0,0,....)$

I want to use the definition of the multiplication of two power series to calculate the inverse.

$c_0=1=\sum_{k=0}^{n=0} (k+1)b_{n-k}=1b_{0}$

$c_1=0=\sum_{k=0}^{n=1} (k+1)b_{n-k}=1b_1+2b_0$

$c_2=0=b_2+2b_1+3b_0$

$c_3=0=b_3+2b_2+3b_1+4b_0$

I did calculate a few of the $b_j's$, I got
$b_0=1, b_1=-2, b_2=1,b_3=0$

How do I continue from here on ?
I would like to write the inverse as power series.

Comment: Duplicate: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/53384/power-series-of-the-reciprocal-does-a-recursive-formula-exist-for-the-coeffic (I can't flag it since it's not on Math.SE)

Comment: The formulas for the first several coefficients of the inverse can be found in many books devoted to tables of integrals and series.

Comment: You can stop here. The inverse is $1-2x+x^2$ as you can verify.

Comment: @Somos, thanks I didn't recognice that the other coefficients are zero

Comment: That verification is not so far from computing that all the other coefficients are $0$, so what is the question here?